# R: Why is my map including the entire world WSG84 space, when all I want plotted is New Zealand?

Tags: r, wgs84, epsg, plot

This seems to be a very easy problem to solve, but about two hours of searching hasn't led me to the answer.

I have [a GIS file](https://koordinates.com/from/datafinder.stats.govt.nz/layer/25743/) that I downloaded in WSG84 ESPG:4326. I read in the file using `readOGR`.

I can't get the file to `plot()` correctly.

Code:

```
NZAreas <- readOGR("[FILEPATH]/area-unit-2013.shp")
proj4string(NZAreas)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

When I `plot(NZAreas)`, I get a very small New Zealand off to the far right of an otherwise-empty plot (apart from one small polygon to the very left) - I seem to be plotting the entire world WGS84 instead of *just* New Zealand

Thinking it might be to do with the apparently absent EPSG code, I also tried:

```
NZAreas <- spTransform(NZAreas, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
plot(NZAreas)
```

This gives me the same small New Zealand on the large empty world map.

Earlier today I had this working. Then after working on some later code, and coming back to this map to plot, the plot no longer limits the area to New Zealand. I can't pinpoint what I am doing wrong. For example, [this blog post](http://rfunctions.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-project-coordinates-rasters-and.html) gives an example of using WGS84 with Brazil data, and having the map limited to only Brazil. To my eye, which is now tired, I am using the same code and getting a different result.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Is the map plot output controlled by something other than the coordinate information in the shapefile? I don't do GIS very often, and I recall this problem bit me the last time I was working in GIS. Looking at my files from back then, I can't see how I solved the problem. But I used all different data for that work.

Comment: Because your data is straddling the antimeridian and you are using a projection that is split at the antimeridian

Comment: Could it be as easy as adding in xlim=c() and ylim=c() values in plot()?

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded the NZ projection (NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000) and it is working perfectly now.